# wordpress theme - need to add if condition and a side bar to a full width theme

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, themes

i have problem in my wp-website , theme (pure)

the problem with theme pure is .. it takes every image .. increase its width to the span's width ( span 8 = 90% ) which is great with normal pictures but some of my posts have smily faces and rating stars .. resized to the max in very bad way

i kept tweaking around and i found that

in theme.css

```
.fw .contentarea .span8 img {


width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

when i change the 100% to 15% .. the smiley faces became normal but also the featured images inside the post.

i would like to make a conditional statement inside the css to ask it to ignore resizeing images if its smaller than 100px

---

second part of the problem is .. pure theme have tons of great features but its a full width theme .. there is no side bars ...

i want to create a sidebar on it so i can add login detail,feeds-scroll & some ads for my website.

my website is nut-job.co .. i have installed a nice chat system on it so u guys can came and chat with me and tell me what to do/try live ... if i am online.

Comment: Your support team at Stack Overflow will probably reject your invitation to come to your website and help you for free. Maybe read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: if i had money i wouldn't came here at the first place would i ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no real conditions in CSS as it's not a programming language. But you can for example add `.responsive` class to all images that need to be responsive and change the CSS to

```
.fw .contentarea .span8 img.responsive {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: i temprarly fixed it by removing width:100%

Comment: i removed width:100% and it got fixed !